# Come join me for some midday fun!

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, outer-space, family

The second of many fun riddles to come,
lets take your social media skills for a run.
You'll need them in full swing,
to find what i am,
if you guessed I'm a man,
 for you the riddle has just began :)

I've sang and sung,
and even acted for a short run.
My significant other has just dabbled in just one.
The little brother of the man who calls thunder,
can make you wonder,
how we first met,
in two thousand and nine,
on a movie set.

For my hand to take an age old gesture he must make.
The receiver of which is of course who you seek,
It's in his name where you may get a peek.

For the rest of my name look to yourself,
however you wont see me.
Maybe try space, not the kind your X requests,
but where celestial bodies may lay to rest,
until i spot them on my epic quest!

Hint:

> You might want to grab a corona with the man the gesture is made to ;)

Hint 2:

> In Old Persian and Babylonian Cyrus means "Sun."

Hint 3:

> The "X" rather than "ex" in the 3rd stanza is significant.

Comment: Wounder - as it is, or did you mean wonder?

Comment: Thanks Paige! I am very poor at proof reading, but that's what team work is for tee hee.

Comment: `The little brother of the man who calls thunder,` that's got to be Liam Hemsworth. And his S.O. (according to google) is Miley Cyrus. Not sure where to go from here though. :P

Comment: @phroureo So Miley and Liam are getting married, what kind of gesture might one make for someones hand in marriage, and who would that gesture be made/given to? Prior to getting her hand of course ;)

Comment: The last two stanzas make me think of spock and star trek, a hand gesture in space, but I'm not sure where to proceed from there...

Comment: @PaigeMeinke I made an edit that's also a hint (but only if you've figured out the previous stanzas correctly). Also look at the tags of the question. The gesture precedes modern times, and is very common place prior to a formal marriage proposal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are...

> Miley Cyrus!

My significant other has just dabbled in just one.
The little brother of the man who calls thunder,

> Liam Hemsworth, significant other of Miley Cyrus, is the little brother of Chris Hemsworth, who played Thor.

how we first met,
in two thousand and nine,
on a movie set.

> Miley and Liam met on the set of The Last Song.

Comment: Almost, you're really close! "if you guessed I'm a man,
for you the riddle has just began :)" applies to male's and females.

Comment: Make sure to look at "For my (Miley) hand to take an age old gesture he (Liam) must make. The receiver of which is of course who you seek, It's in his name where you may get a peek."

Comment: Is it to ask for permission from her father? Cyrus means sun and Ray is also in his name. That satisfies the family tag too.

Comment: Correct!! Now you just have the last stanza to solve, make sure to mind the edit i made recently made.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to guess it's

> Hollywood Boulevard - Walk of Fame

Taking hints from @line_read_line's answer

> The first two stanzas describe Miley and Billy Ray Cyrus

The third stanza remains.

For the rest of my name look to yourself, however you wont see me.

> Billy Ray Cyrus' name won't be visible

Maybe try space, not the kind your X requests,
but where celestial bodies may lay to rest,

> Suggests outer space, "celestial bodies", stars

until i spot them on my epic quest!

> Something everyone is going for. 
>  Miley Cyrus has a star on the walk of fame, but Billy Ray Cyrus does not, therefore you won't see his name, and he may be trying to get one.

Comment: Honestly this solution was so good that i'm inclined to accept it, however it's incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

> Time? This sound reasonable because of how one  "dabbles" with time, testing and trying to be the superior, this might not be right but there are other reasons for this

Comment: No, but you may be on the right track. This riddle really dives around modern celebrities.